# How to access <path> in a SVG document

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, svg, tags

I'm creating several click-able maps - and have been unsuccessful in trying to find how to access a tag for a path so that I can make all the different counties in the map clickable.  (the SVG file is incredibly complicated... this is the structure and I can't change it - it's getting automatically generated for all the different states):

```
<svg width="932.25827pt" height="569.25354pt" viewBox="0 0 932.25827 569.25354" enable-background="new 0 0 932.25827 569.25354"
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<g id="Layers">
    <g id="Ohio_Counties">
        <clipPath id="SVG_CP_1">
            <path d="M0,569.25354L0,0L932.25827,0L932.25827,569.25354L0,569.25354z"/>
        </clipPath>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVG_CP_1)" fill="none" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="0.48003" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
    M374.18483,441.14215L375.38491,440.90214L375.62493,440.90214L376.58499,440.66213L376.82501,440.66213L377.54505,440.42212
            L378.02508,440.42212L378.2651,440.42212L378.74513,440.42212L379.46518,440.66213L381.14529,440.66213L381.38531,440.66213L
            381.62532,440.66213L382.10536,440.66213L382.8254,440.66213L384.50551,440.90214L384.74553,440.90214L386.18563,440.90214L386.42564,441.38217
            L386.42564,441.62218L386.42564,441.86219L386.66566,441.86219L386.90567,441.86219L386.90567,442.1022L386.90567,442.34221L"/>
       </path>   
    </g>
</g>

/* There are about 87 more paths in the file... this is just a part of one.*/
```

I'm using jquery.svg - but haven't found the solution in the documentation.

Here's the javascript:

```
function changeState(newState){
    nS = newState.replace(/\s/g, '');

    try {      
        var map = 'mapLayers/AEP'+nS+'Counties.svg';
            $("#contentCounties").empty();
            var currentCountyMap = $('#contentCounties').svg({loadURL: loc, onLoad: addClickEvents(this)});

        } catch(err){
           alert("the map " + currentCountyMap + " does not exist");
    }
}


function addClickEvents(){
    // this is where I want to put the code to 
    // add click events to the individual paths.
    // Whether it's running a loop or using a jquery selector
    // I'm fine with either.

    // This is, in theory, what I think I want - but alas, it is wrong:
    var svg=document.getElementByTagName("path");
    alert(svg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've just left the s out of getElementsByTagName